# Access a file only via jQuery-Ajax & PHP (no direct URL access)

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

i've some links which i'm using like

jQuery:

```
$("a.sync").on("click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr("href");
  $.post(url,function(data){
    $("#stage").html(data);
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a class="sync" href="__home.php">Link</a>
```

this link just revieves data from another page and put it to #stage asyncly.
but using inspect element user can see the link **__home.php** and can directly access it using custom URL.
I dont want users to directly access that file, but only with Ajax call...
how to do it?

Comment: You can put: `var url = "__home.php";`, but this is also discoverable by the inspector...!

Comment: send along a variable with your ajax call and check for that in the php file you are retrieving.

Answer (score 1):

You can't deny direct access completely ( someone can imitate ajax request), иге you can make it more difficult. First, try to check $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] at __home.php . Second - read about CSRF tokens

Answer (score 0):

This may prove very difficult because the file you're accessing via AJAX has to be public content to the user browsing the site - *The AJAX-call is anyway triggered by the client from the perspective of the backend*.

You could employ some sort of tokens as parameters, for example, but the problem is that the token must be known by the Javascript code, which is sending the request, and hence it is ultimately known by the user browsing the site also.

Flash probably enables usage of file system files but I'm unfamiliar with this and it seems a bit overkill.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
$("a.sync").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr("href");
  $("#stage").load(data);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: that is not what im talking about... i want to hide or deny access to the url on direct access